# VideoCapture.read() using OpenCV. Why is USB Camera faster than CSI Camera? (NO GPU)

Tags: 16.04, python, camera, opencv, v4l

I am using NanoPi Duo 2 for the real-time image acquisition project.

I have noticed a significant performance (speed) difference between using CSI camera and USB camera.

---

The performance difference is as follows,
**Time for OpenCV VideoCapture.read()**

```
CSI_OV5640_Camera = ~0.04s (40 ms)
USB_Logitech_HD_C270 = ~0.009 (9 ms)
```

---

As far as I know, I understand that NanoPi Duo2 does not have any GPU and CSI camera will be handled by CPU (Same as USB Camera).

Using `$ htop` both CSI and USB cameras shows 100% @ one of 4 cores.

**Update: Output frame handling requires more CPU power with CSI camera.**

---

For background,

**OpenCV 3.4.6 Build Output**

```
Video I/O
 - libv4l/libv4l2    NO
 - v4l/v4l2          linux/videodev2.h
```

**$ v4l2-ctl --get-fmt-video**

```
Format Video Capture:
        Width/Height      : 640/480
        Pixel Format      : 'YV12'
        Field             : Any
        Bytes per Line    : 960
        Size Image        : 460800
        Colorspace        : Default
        Transfer Function : Default
        YCbCr Encoding    : Default
        Quantization      : Default
        Flags             :
```

**One interesting thing**
Performance of using `numpy ndarray` from CSI and USB are ALSO different

```
pyzbar.decode() calculation
CSI_OV5640_Camera = ~0.43s (430 ms)
USB_Logitech_HD_C270 = ~0.19s (190 ms)
```

---

I am thinking that encoding of the VideoCapture.read() are different but all I see is same sized (640x480, 3 colors) numpy ndarray with similar looking values. However the array received using CSI camera requires much higher CPU power to process somehow.

Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is having similar issue, I have found a reason using `$ htop`.

This was related to the different CPU consumption as CSI camera requires more CPU.

---

#### With CSI Camera (OV5640)

> Continuous VideoCapture.read() occupies full CPU power (100% @ all 4 cores)

---

#### With USB Camera (Logitech C270)

> continuous VideoCapture.read() occupies maximum 60-70% CPU power only at 1 core.

---

I want to know further why CSI requires more CPU power than USB UVC camera but this should be a separate question.